# Updating Bridging-Header File

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, bridging-header

I've got an Objective C project and I'm trying to use Swift file in it. I've added swift file and Xcode automatically created Bridging Header. So I could create an object of my swift class in obj-c file and access to its properties. But then I added a new string to my swift file. And I can’t access a new-added property from my objective C file. So I think, I have to update or recreate Bridging Header, haven't I? Can anybody help me?

Comment: The bridging header is used to access Objective-C code from Swift. If you want to access Swift code from Objective-C, you need to do the following import in your Objective-C file: `#import "ProductModuleName-Swift.h`. See Apple's [Migrating Your Objective-C Code to Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/migrating_your_objective_c_code_to_swift).

Comment: @dnlggr That’s exactly what I have done and everything worked fine. But after adding a new var to swift class I can’t access it from Obj C file.

Comment: Ok, I see. Please share a [minimal, complete, and verifiable code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can understand your problem better.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put `@objc` in front of your class or property? like:

```
@objc public class myClass {
  @objc var str: String = "str"
}
```